# How To Load JSON Data from Web Service in Ajax Url Property

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

I have problem when I try to load JSON Data from web service in ajax url. So far, I code this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $('#kategoriTable').dataTable({
            ajax: {
            url : "http://localhost:90/kugi_deployment/api/json/reply/KategoriRetrieve",
            dataSrc : function(json) {
               console.log(json);
               return json.Kategoris
            }
        },
        //data : testData.Kategoris,
           columns: [
              { data: "KodeKategori"},
              { data: "Nama"},
              { data: "Definisi"},
              { data: "UnsurAbstrak"},
              { data: "Alias"},
              { data: "SumberDefinisi"},
              { data: "Tanggal"},
              { data: "TipeTanggal"},
              { data: "Edisi"},
              { data: "Role"},
              { data: "OtherCitationDetail"},
              { data: "NamaKatalog"},
              { data: "NamaOrganisasi"}
           ]
        });
</script>
```

The url property in ajax did not response and load the data. Here is my browser showed the error:
[image: It is loading forever when I try to load that data]

Can anyone help me to fix this thing? Thanks

Comment: Solved it bro. What a stupid mistake I've done!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED by myself
The main mistake I do is put the `file_get_contents` in function index (I am using CodeIgniter). When I put all things to another function it successfully show the data I want. Thanks